# Don't know how to read the variables in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I just have started my work with Tkinter and created my first test GUI. I want to make a simple program that can help me to understand how it works. I have 3 input parameters (weight, sex, number of people) and would like to have one output parameter "weight of person = weight/number of people". I would like to print phrase "The weight of each {sex} is {weight of person}" in the GUI TEXT frame if I click "GET" button and Checkbutton "Print" is marked or just print this phrase in Command Prompt if not marked. Currently I don't know how to take the entrance values from interface - I tried several methods, but it doesn't work. I guess there is a very simple solution, but I can't see it :( Could you kindly help with this question?

```
​from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext

class MyGUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()
        parent.title("My first GUI)")

    def initUI(self):              
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        Style().configure("TFrame")       

        ####--- First Frame---------------------------------------------------------
        frame1 = Frame(self,relief=RAISED,width=700,height=37)
        frame1.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)

        ''' First '''
        ####--- Second Frame-------------------------------------------------------
        frameW1 = Frame(self,relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1,width=230,height=300)
        frameW1.pack(anchor='w',side=LEFT,expand=TRUE,fill=BOTH)

        frame2 = Frame(frameW1,relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1,width=230,height=135)
        frame2.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)

        #section title
        label1 = Label(frame2, text="Parameters:", font=("Arial Bold", 9))
        label1.place(x=0, y=2) 

        status0 = IntVar()
        chk = Checkbutton(frame2, text="Print",var=status0,onvalue=1,offvalue=0,command=self.CheckFunc)  
        chk.place(x=15, y=25)

        #Total weight
        v1 = Label(frame2, text="Weight [kg]:", width=25)
        v1.place(x=15, y=50)  
        p1 = Entry(frame2,width=11)
        p1.place(x=145, y=50)  

        #Sex
        v3 = Label(frame2, text="Sex:", width=25)
        v3.place(x=15, y=75)  
        n3=IntVar()
        p3 = Combobox(frame2, width=8,textvariable=n3)
        p3['values']= ("Male", "Femail")
        p3.place(x=145, y=75)

        #Number of people
        v2 = Label(frame2,text='Number of people:',width=25)
        v2.place(x=15, y=100)       
        p2 = Entry(frame2,width=11)
        p2.place(x=145, y=100)   

        ##############################################################################
        #TEXT frame 
        frame3 = Frame(frameW1,relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1,width=230,height=130)
        frame3.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)
        txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(frame3,width=25,height=7)
        txt.place(x=5, y=5) 
        txt.insert(INSERT,'Status ...')

        ##############################################################################
        #Button frame 
        frame4 = Frame(frameW1,relief=RAISED, borderwidth=1,width=230,height=120)
        frame4.pack(side=TOP,expand=True,fill=X)
        getButton = Button(frame4, text="GET", command=self.my_print)
        self.result = StringVar()
        getButton.pack(side=LEFT)     

    def my_print(self):
        print('Check box value...')
        result=int(p1/p2)
        quote = "Each of " + str(p2)+ " " + str(p3)+ " has a weight = " + str(result) + "kg" 
        self.txt.insert(END, quote)

    def CheckFunc(self):
        pass

root = Tk()
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(230,335)) 
app = MyGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a value from a widget like an Entry u can use the method .get() like this: YourEntryName.get() and be sure to always place your widgets in different lines basically u are doing good by declaring a variable of a tkinter object and then placing it because if not, when u run .get() in that entry it will return NONE, when u need to work with a certain widget u can just declare the variable in one line and in the next one place it on the frame or window or whatever.
Another way to get is the widget name and using the method .cget() and passing an argument wich would be the key that u wan't to get, for example in a Label you would do : yourLabelName.cget(text) and this way you will get the text that yourLabelName has at that moment!
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Tiago, thank you for your answer. I added get.() functions to the code, but still there is an error that variables are not defined.  For example, I simple I added p1.get() after p1 = Entry(frame2,width=11) and etc for p2, p3..

Comment: when using .get() function, use that only when u need to get that value

Comment: u still have to place the widgets, idk if u didn't

Comment: Nice that's awesome!, just make sure to upvote my answer so it counts as answer, so other people now that what i said will fix that problem u had :D